# Axis2 problem with concurrent requests mismatch response object

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm facing a problem on my production server for a Web Service with concurrent requests.

The problem is that when the Web Service receives (for instance) two requests for two different methods (each method returning a different object) in the same service, the Web Service will return the object type of the second request.

To replicate and simply the problem I create a simple Web Service with only one service and two methods with the same environment of the production server.

### Code (*RequestMethods.class*)

```
package test;

import beans.Request1Response;
import beans.Request2Response;

public class RequestMethods {

    public Request1Response request1() {
        Request1Response output = new Request1Response();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        output.setError_code(1);
        output.setError_msg("message1");

        return output;
    }

    public Request2Response request2() {
        Request2Response output = new Request2Response();

        output.setError_code(2);
        output.setError_msg("message2");

        return output;
    }

}
```

### Configurations (*services.xml*)

```
<service name="RequestMethods">
    <Description>
        Concurrent Requests test
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">test.RequestMethods</parameter>
</service>
```

### Test

I've made a request for *request1* and before this one returns, made another request for *request2*.

Result for *request1* (the first request but the second obtained response):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:request2Response xmlns:ns="http://test/xsd">
         <ns:return>
            <error_code xmlns="http://beans/xsd">1</error_code>
            <error_msg xmlns="http://beans/xsd">message1</error_msg>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:request2Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Result for *request2* (the second request but the first obtained response):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:request2Response xmlns:ns="http://test/xsd">
         <ns:return>
            <error_code xmlns="http://beans/xsd">2</error_code>
            <error_msg xmlns="http://beans/xsd">message2</error_msg>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:request2Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see above, the response for *request1* it should be of type *request1Response* but it's from *request2Response* instead.

The environment I'm using is:

- Tomcat 5.5.25 for the application server
- Axis2 1.2 for the Web Service
- Java version 1.5.0_11

Is anyone also facing this problem or knows how to solve it? 
I already tried to change the Axis2 version to 1.6 but the problem persists.

Any help is well appreciated.

Regards,
João

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for this problem.

When you have a service (*RequestMethods*) with more than one method defined (*request1* and *request2*), it's necessary to set one *RPCMessageReceiver* for each method to avoid concurrency problems.

You can define one *MessageReceiver* for each method on file *services.xml*.

In the example I post, the file *services.xml* should be like this:

### services.xml

```
<service name="RequestMethods">
    <Description>
        Concurrent Requests test
    </Description>
    <operation name="request1"> 
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/> 
    </operation>
    <operation name="request2"> 
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/> 
    </operation> 
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">test.RequestMethods</parameter>
</service>
```